# MySQL query for 24 hours, 00.00 - 23.59

Tags: php, mysql

How do I query for 24 hours? start at 00.00 end at 23.59.59?

i use this query, but the result, just get last 24 hours..

```
mysql_query('select * from fe1b WHERE waktu_fe1b >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY');
```

The problem with that is that it  gets last 24 hours. It doesn't get the from 00.00 - 23.59.59

Comment: What day do you want the 24 hours on? Today? Yesterday? 27th June 1992?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TO_DAYS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) method for it. This will change a date to the days since year 0. So it will be the same for every datetime from `00:00` till `23:59` on the same day

Also I advise you to discontinue the use of `mysql_query` because its deprecated. See [why shouldnt I use mysql functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

```
$query = 'select * from fe1b WHERE TO_DAYS(waktu_fe1b) = TO_DAYS(now())';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Query U will get it:

```
mysql_query('select * from fe1b WHERE waktu_fe1b <> subdate(current_date, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query('select * from fe1b WHERE waktu_fe1b >= (DATE(now()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult, I had to look it up. But it seems like you can use the following code:

```
mysql_query("SELECT NOW(), DATE_SUB( DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL +59 SECOND), INTERVAL '+23:59' HOUR_MINUTE)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for selecting everything from the previous day, and is easier to maintain in my opinion:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND column < CURRENT_DATE;
```

So for your purpose, it would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM fe1b
WHERE waktu_fe1b >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND waktu_fe1b < CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: the result, yesterday, 00-23.59..  by the way, thank for sharing it